# merge x python dictionaries into 1 with aggregated values

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries with the same key names, I want to consolidate the dictionaries into one dictionary with averaged values only in number-based values:

```
[{'a': 3, 'b': 'm', 'c': 7}, 
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 'm', 'c': 2}, 
{'a': 5, 'b': 'm', 'c': 4.0}]
```

into an averaged dictionary:

```
[{'a': 3, 'b': 'm', 'c': 4}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume you have at least one dict in the list and all the dicts have all the keys you can do:

```
import numbers
dicts =[{'a': 3, 'b': 'm', 'c': 7},
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 'm', 'c': 2},
{'a': 5, 'b': 'm', 'c': 4.0}]

avg_dict = {}
for key in dicts[0]:
        avg_dict[key] = sum([d[key] for d in dicts])/len(dicts) if isinstance(dicts[0][key], numbers.Number) else dicts[0][key]
```

Comment: That's great, worked a treat. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most pythonic way, but it will do the job:

```
lst = [{'a': 3, 'b': 'm', 'c': 7}, 
       {'a': 1.0, 'b': 'm', 'c': 2}, 
       {'a': 5, 'b': 'm', 'c': 4.0}]

result = {}

for item in lst:
    for j in item:
        if type(item[j]) == str:
            result[j] = item[j]
        elif j in result:
            result[j] += item[j]
        else:
            result[j] = item[j]

for i in result:
    if type(result[i]) != str:
        result[i] = int(result[i] / len(lst))

print(result)
```